# Restart counter every week

Tags: javascript, html, counter

I would like to create a counter that reset every week, I found a code that more or less works, but when It goes to 0, it appears negative.... -1d -1h -2m -5s

```
            <script>
            // Set the date we're counting down to
            var countDownDate = new Date("Jan 29, 2021 20:21:0").getTime();

            // Update the count down every 1 second
            var x = setInterval(function() {

            // Get todays date and time
            var now = new Date().getTime();

            // Find the distance between now an the count down date
            var distance = countDownDate - now;

            // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
            var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
            var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
            var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
            var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

            // Display the result in the element with id="demo"
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = days + "d " + hours + "h "
            + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";

            // If the count down is finished, write some text
            if (distance < 0) {
                //document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "GAME DAY";
                if(distance < - 1000 * 60 * 60* 24){ // if its past the "game day"
                    // reset timer to next week
                    countDownDate += 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7
                }
            }
        }, 1000);
      </script>
      <span id="demo"></span>
```

Comment: This counter is supposed to count down from when to when? If you want the counter to reset every week, why is `Jan 29, 2021 20:21:0` hardcoded? Distance being < 0 doesn't change any of the calculations above it, so the behavior you're seeing is exactly what the code says to do. Maybe move the branch up or kill the countdown before writing to the DOM?

Comment: I was just testing, I wanted to count it, from Friday to Friday

Comment: You want it to count down from 8:21 PM each Friday and show the time left in h:m:s until 8:21 PM the next Friday?

Comment: Correct, well 8:00 exactly , each Friday, when it reaches 0, it resets and counts again until next Friday

Comment: OK, thanks for clarifying. When do you want "game day" to display? I'm guessing maybe the hour or two after 8 PM should show this (the game is live) or should it immediately start the next week's countdown?

Comment: Thank you for helping me :) Yes, an hour would work perfect!

Comment: @ggorlen did you manage to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of hard-coding the date, you need to calculate the next date based on the current date.

Something like this, though you'd be better of moving the magic numbers (`5` and `20`) into variables.

```js
let getNextGameDayTime = function() {
  let now = new Date();
  let dayOfTheWeek = now.getDay();
  let dayOffset = 5 - dayOfTheWeek; // Friday is the 5th day of the week
  if (dayOffset < 0 || (dayOffset === 0 && now.getHours() > 20)) {
   dayOffset += 7;
  }
  let result = new Date();
  result.setDate(result.getDate() + dayOffset);
  result.setHours(20);
  result.setMinutes(0);
  result.setSeconds(0);
  result.setMilliseconds(0);
  return result;
}

console.log(getNextGameDayTime());
```

As for not displaying the message for the hour after a countdown has finished, you could use the resulting distance for this.

Comment: Looks great! But instead of console.log how can I add it to my html?

Comment: Well this is just the code to calculate the `countDownDate`. The rest of your code should still work.